C# Program cannot ReadKey when Python is running it as a subprocess
I have a C# app that runs perfectly fine when executing it through a command line terminal or manually executing it. When using a python script to run the C# app, the program spits out the following error:
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read. at System.Console.ReadKey(Boolean intercept)

Is there a reason why the program cannot read keys when run using subprocess.Popen in python?
p = subprocess.Popen(
    f"SomeCSharpProgram.exe",
    stdin=PIPE,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
    shell=True
)
output, error = p.communicate(input=b'\n')


As the exception states, ReadKey needs a direct connection to a console window to receive key presses from there.

Console.ReadKey calls API entry points in the background that require a standard console handle. This works as long as your program is running directly in a standard console - launched by cmd.exe or run directly.
In this case however you're using Popen which uses redirection on the various standard streams (stdin, stdout, stderr). In this situation there's no connection to the actual console, so anything (such as Console.ReadKey) that relies on having a console to work directly on will no longer function.
All of which is implied in your error message:

Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.

(It should include "or other stream" for completeness.)
You may be able to get around this using os.system(...) to run your program. Everything I'm reading seems to indicate that by default it uses proper console interaction, but there's not a lot of information about it with respect to Windows.

Using os.system(...) still causes the same exception to occur unfortunately.
I was able to solve it by passing creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE as an argument to the popen() call. Just need to find a way to pass a key entry in so the new console closes.

@tyleax Glad you found a solution. You can write up your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it (there may be a delay before you can accept) so that people searching for the same problem have an answer they can refer to.
